# GetAdaptersInfo (c++)function not working on vista and windows 7

Tags: c++

i am using GetAdaptersInfo on windows xp to retrieve mac address.its working well on xp but neither on vista nor on windows 7.
Is GetAdaptersInfo supported by windows 7 and vista. if no what api should i use to get mac address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DWORD GetAdaptersInfo(
  PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo,
  PULONG pOutBufLen
);
```

How did you allocate memory for `pAdapterInfo`? Seems that there is some issue with stack allocation of this [in] parameter.

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/peertopeer/thread/6d9455b6-bbe8-41c8-9f69-efb14943e238)

Comment: thanx worked on windows 7 but not on vista.is it really support vista?